# How do I get rid of this protrusion in my components using CircuiTikz

Tags: circuitikz

The following code produces weird protrusion in my components. How do I get rid of them.
[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[european,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[european]
    \draw (0,0) to [short, o-] (1,0) to [ R=$R_1$] (2,0) to [short] (3,0) to [ R=$R_1$] (4,0) to [short, -o] (5,0) 
    (2.5,0) to [short] (2.5,-0.5) to [R=$R_2$] (2.5, -1.5) to [short] (2.5, -2)
    (0,-2) to [short, o-o] (5,-2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This was easy enough to tackle, but please, next time show us a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have too little space between the component. The default size of the components is based on a basic length (see the manual!) which is by default 1.4cm. You are allowing just 1cm, so the overlap.

You can either add space:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[european]
    \draw (0,0) to [short, o-] (1,0) to [ R=$R_1$] (3,0) to [short] (4,0) to [ R=$R_1$] (6,0) to [short, -o] (7,0) 
    (3.5,0) to [short] (3.5,-0.5) to [R=$R_2$] (3.5, -2.5) to [short] (3.5, -3)
    (0,-3) to [short, o-o] (7,-3);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: putout from the code above]

or use smaller components by reducing the value of `bipoles/length` (which is the basic length for all `circuitikz`, see manual around page 33). Notice that this will change the proportions between components and the size of the font used in the labels, which is not affected — you may like it or not.

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=1cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[european]
    \draw (0,0) to [short, o-] (1,0) to [ R=$R_1$] (2,0) to [short] (3,0) to [ R=$R_1$] (4,0) to [short, -o] (5,0) 
    (2.5,0) to [short] (2.5,-0.5) to [R=$R_2$] (2.5, -1.5) to [short] (2.5, -2)
    (0,-2) to [short, o-o] (5,-2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: output with smaller components]

Anyway, if you are serious about using `circuitikz`, do yourself a favor and learn to use named/relative coordinates. It will pay off greatly... (see the tutorials in the manual).